Unknown Object in 3d View Port - Yellow Arch with Red Twisted Circular Lines - 4.1.0
TLDR:

Transparent Yellow Arch with Red Twisted Circular Lines in 3D View Port
shows in version 4.1 not 4.0.2
all addons disabled
unable to find any settings that effect
unable to select/effect
no noticable effect beyond visually as a 3d object that can be navigated around
does not render, even through view port render
See attached images
Does not show up in new blender file
Would like to know if anyone knows how to disable? What is the cause? What is it for?

After recently upgrading to 4.1.0 wth a fresh install and begining to continue working on a project I have been doing for a while (architectual layout...). After changing some setting, possibly installing an addon, that I have since removed (which means I am not sure what might be the cause or what addon could have caused the issue). An odd tranparent yellow half hollow cylinder/arch with a connection between the 2 lower areas that red twisted red marks on it showed up in my 3d view port.  I have disable all addons, even default ones that come with Blender, and looked through all settings that I can possibly think to check. I have been unable to make the object go away. No object in the outliner corresponds to the object, checked by disabling all objects in the scene. Unable to select or effect in any way. Object is just in the scene and I can move around it in the 3d space. I have opened the file in the previous version of Blender to check if it was something that possibly followed between the version, but it does not.
Besides the object just being visually annoying to have always in the 3d view port, it causes zero noticable effects to the scene.
My guess is it has something to do with something I added randomly for lighting but I am unsure, as I have since simplified the lighting and am just working with just a HDRI.




I can only recommend opening a new scene without the object, then append all objects from your project file (when  this arch does not show up in the outliner I would guess it should not be appended) and then save it and delete the old file. No other ideas because I have never seen that before.

Thank you Gordon.This is what I will end up doing for sure. It's just such an odd thing to just suddenly appear and have no way to turn it off, select it, or understand what functionality it might have. I might clear the file out of any of my project assets, assuming it will stay in the file once I do this, then post it up for someone, if anyone wants to, to dismantle it and figure out what it is.
